# jQuery - Setting background position from variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im getting the X and Y co-ordinates or a selected area, Im then using that to set the position of an image in another DIV.

Vars:

```
selection.x1 (This will need to be a negative value)
selection.y2
```

I need to write using Javascript or jQuery the following:

```
div.css('background-position', -selection.xl selection.y2);
```

But this just give me an error, how can I add two background postion values to the CSS?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var x1 = '-100';
var y2 = '100';

$('#divID').css({
  'background-position':x1+'px '+y2+'px'
});
```

That works for me, just ensure you have a `background-position` in your css as well (even if it's set to `0px 0px`

**Edit for @logic-unit**
`$('#divID').css('background-position', x1+'px '+y2+'px');`

Comment: @logic-unit When setting a single property `.css(...)` use `,` after the property name. When setting multiple properties / using an array `.css({....})` use `:` after the property name. http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2